# Is there any method to update all XML nodes values to trimmed values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is one XML example:

```
<Addresses>
    <Address>
        <Line1>ASHKD JUDUD dj</Line1>
        <Line2>   HSGKDJ JDJDY JJDHC</Line2>
        <Line3>KSJHD DJJDJ tqSJNC   </Line3>
        <Line4> SJKUnxc JDJDJ</Line4>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <Line1>DKWUHD JDJCND</Line1>
        <Line2>SKDHWY DHCBo ICUN</Line2>
        <Line3>  TSDJk SDKJDUbn UDU</Line3>
        <Line4>297476 3837  </Line4>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <Line1>AAA BB CC DD</Line1>
        <Line2> BB KDJUJD DJKCNUW KDJK</Line2>
        <Line3>LSIDCN JDCBDU  ddn    </Line3>
        <Line4>   BXNBDki odioIOSJCX</Line4>
        <Phone>  8273 3937 </Phone>
        <City>  KSDUC SJDHCU</City>
    </Address>
</Addresses>
```

Is there any generic method to modify any nodes to trim-ed values?

Comment: Is it in a table or a variable? Are all the XML documents the same layout

Comment: This is a variable and XML documents are not same, there are over 5x layout.

Comment: Please show all the layouts then. When I said layout I mean: a root `Addresses` node, with child `Address` nodes, with those child nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, XQuery `.modify` only works on a single node. You have two options:

1. Run it in a loop.

   - The syntax `//*/text()` finds any descendant node's inner text
   - `[(substring(., 1, 1), substring(., string-length(.) - 1, 1)) = " "]` checks if either the first or last character in the text is   . Here the `.` means "current value"
   - We store that in a variable (bailing out if it's null), trim it...
   - Then store it back using `.modify` with `replace value of`

```sql
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @val nvarchar(max) = @xml.value('(//*/text()[(substring(., 1, 1), substring(., string-length(.) - 1, 1)) = " "])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    IF @val IS NULL
        BREAK;
    
    SET @val = TRIM(@val);
    SET @xml.modify('
        replace value of
          (//*/text()[(substring(., 1, 1), substring(., string-length(.) - 1, 1)) = " "])[1]
        with sql:variable("@val")
        ');
END;

SELECT @xml;
```

2. Rebuild the whole XML. You obviously need to know the exact layout of the XML to do this.

   - Shred it into rows using `.nodes`.
   - Get each value using `.value`
   - `TRIM` it.
   - Recreate the XML using `FOR XML`

```sql
SELECT
  TRIM(x.addr.value('(Line1/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) Line1,
  TRIM(x.addr.value('(Line2/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) Line2,
  TRIM(x.addr.value('(Line3/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) Line3,
  TRIM(x.addr.value('(Line4/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) Line4,
  TRIM(x.addr.value('(Phone/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) Phone,
  TRIM(x.addr.value('(City /text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) City
FROM @xml.nodes('/Addresses/Address') x(addr)
FOR XML PATH('Address'), ROOT('Addresses'), TYPE;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb3500ff7bb9fefa5e2db7e0a70e79b8)